# Is this proper way to add validators to existing ones in Custom Form Control?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm wondering whether my solution is correct. In my application I'm using Reactive Form and to my **CustomFormControl** (that implements ControlValueAccessor) I've added validator `myControl: ["", Validators.required]`. This validator is needed only on a few pages, that's why is added by formBuilder.

But also I need to have validators that will be used always for that control. So to make it work in my control I had had to add token `NG_VALIDATORS` which allows me to use `validate()` method, which as far I know is triggered every time when control need to be validated:

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-control",
    templateUrl: "./my-control.component.html",
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: MyControlComponent,
            multi: true
        },
        {
            provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
            useExisting: MyControlComponent,
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class MyControlComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

    ...

    validate(value: AbstractControl): void {
        value.setValidators(Validators.compose([value.validator, Validators.min(0), Validators.max(200)]));
    }
}
```

Note that I have `value.validator` because I want to merge existing validators (added in form builder) with these `min` and `max` validators. Everything works fine but is it a proper solution, because I couldn't find such case in google.

Answer (score 1):

I found better solution, validators can be added directly in providers array.

```
providers: [
    {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useValue: Validators.min(0), multi: true},
    {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useValue: Validators.max(200), multi: true},
]
```